# Are there any prices given for the Tomes of Clear Thought, Leadership, and Influence?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, pricing

The source '[Sane Magical Prices](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?424243-Sane-Magic-Item-Prices)' by Saidoro lists prices for many of the magic items found in the DMG, but the Tomes are inexplicably omitted.  The suggested prices for a 'Very Rare' item in the DMG can range anywhere from 5001-50000 gp.

Are there any prices listed in another supplement, perhaps?

Comment: Are you asking for official prices only, or any?

Answer (score 11):

## About Sane Magical Prices

First, Sane Magical Prices does tell us why they aren't priced.

> Manuals and tomes +2: If these come up, the GM is probably giving them to the whole party as a "level up" type thing

Essentially, the author is interested in items that would usually be sold - Tomes are hardly the case since they would probably already be used, and buying them isn't the common way to get them.

Note that the guide you mention is not a Supplement or official in any way. It's a house rule by a random guy that made a really good and well accepted job.

## Guideline on Prices

As you said, for very rare from DMG, prices go from 5k to 50k gp. In XGtE (p. 126), the prices for very rare items are listed as (1d4 + 1) x 10k, so still max 50k, but min is now 20k. For consumables, that price should be halved - Tomes are not usually handled as consumables since they give a permanent ASI though.

There are more details on how to actually buy magical items in both books, but for pricing, these are the values.

### Personal note

I agree with Sane Magical Prices' opinion on Tomes. I would give them as rewards for someone too far behind in stats (e.g. someone that rolled too low) or, at best, to some MAD class. Allowing players to buy them could take away the whole thinking when leveling up and what feats are worth to get - essentially, when you give free ASI, you are actually giving a free feat.

Answer (score 4):

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* contains a section in chapter 2, under Downtime Activities, describing an (official, unlike Sane Magical Prices) optional way to handle the purchasing of magical items and their prices. The subsection, titled ["Buying a Magic Item"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/downtime-revisited#BuyingaMagicItem), is on p. 126.

As just the price doesn't do the buying process justice and quoting the entire section would be a lot of copyrighted text, you'll need to buy or borrow the book for the details.

Comment: You should probably mention that Sane Magical Prices is not an official supplement at all in case that was a point of confusion. They do seem to call it a "supplement" which it is not in any real sense of the word.

Comment: In case people *do* have XGtE you could include a page number reference... I can't find such a section, for example, in my copy...

Comment: p. 126, Isaac. It's under Buying magic items.

Comment: Oop - yep, just found it. I was expecting it to be in the "Awarding Magic Items" section, and when I skimmed the "Downtime Revisited" section of the Table of Contents I did so quickly and missed it.

Comment: I own only the dndbeyond version, and so have no page numbers. I'll put the chapter, though, and thanks HellSaint for the page.

Comment: Even if it doesn't "do the process justice", I think it's still worth quoting the relevant suggested prices, even if you don't quote every detail about the process. (XGtE suggests an asking price of "(1d4 + 1) × 10,000 gp" for very rare items, as the Tome of Clear Thought, the Tome of Leadership and Influence, and the Tome of Understanding all are.)